# Not so obvious error while copying .DAT file

Tags: video-conversion

There is a .DAT file saved on video CD which is to be saved on SD card. The usual copy paste procedure failed midway showing error "can't read file". The operation was executed by using explorer as well as terra copy, but error persists. Can any suggestion be made for eliminating the error or any other way to execute the operation.

Details regarding file :
Format: .DAT
Size: 700 MB

Details regarding destination:
SD card
Space available: 2GB

Comment: Do we talk about VIdeo-CD?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes

Comment: You can't copy the video (DAT file) from VIdeoCD, you should rip the video. This may help: https://superuser.com/a/691243/409497